# Jupyter magic defined from instance method

Tags: python, methods, jupyter-notebook, python-decorators

I am writing a class that sends slack messages to users when processes have finished. I thought it would be useful to provide a Jupyter magic so that users can be notified when the cell is executed.

The class already provides a decorator, so I figured I'd just wrap a cell execution in a decorated function.

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
from IPython import get_ipython

import functools

class MyClass(object):

    def decorate(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            r = f(*args, **kwargs)
            print('Send a message here!')
            return r
        return wrapped

    @register_cell_magic
    def magic(self, line, cell):
        ip = get_ipython()
        @self.decorate
        def f():
            return ip.run_cell(cell)
        return f()
```

So then I'd do:

```
obj = MyClass()

# ----- NEW CELL
%%obj.magic
'''do some stuff'''
```

But I get

```
>> UsageError: Cell magic `%%obj.magic` not found.
```

I found out that the magic is registered under its name (above, `magic`), so `%%magic` works. But then the arguments are all messed up because there is no `self` in the mix.

I want the magic to be an instance method so that config (set in `__init__` can be used). Is there any way to do this?

Here are a couple hacky solutions I don't want to implement unless I really have to:

1. Register a regular function with the instance as an argument. I don't want to add that line of code to the notebook, *I want to use an instance method*.
2. Register a regular function that constructs an instance on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can come up with, and it's #1 on the list of the things I didn't want to do.

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
from IPython import get_ipython

import functools

class MyClass(object):

    def decorate(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            r = f(*args, **kwargs)
            print('Send a message here!')
            return r
        return wrapped


    def register_magic(self):
        @register_cell_magic
        def magic(line, cell):
            ip = get_ipython()
            @self.decorate
            def f():
                return ip.run_cell(cell)
            return f()
```

Then

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.register_magic()

# ------
%%magic
...
```